# How to do logging in MEAN Stack

Tags: node.js, express, logging

which is the best way to enable logging in node , express , mongoose application?
I have been using console logging ;but there is no way to turn it on or off during production.
is there something as solid as log4j and can be used in production applications

Comment: https://npms.io/search?q=logging

Answer (score 1):

You can use winston.js, https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#logging-levels
You can use log levels and specify which level to log in console and which into some logfile

```
  var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
transports: [
  new (winston.transports.Console)({ level: 'error' }),
  new (winston.transports.File)({
    filename: 'somefile.log',
    level: 'info'
  })
]
```

});

But there is also log4js https://github.com/nomiddlename/log4js-node

Comment: I have decided to use winston.js itself.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can install `morgan`,
Use `npm install morgan`,

After installing it,require it i.e
`var morgan = require('morgan');`
Since you have express installed,
You can then do this to enable morgan,
`app.use(morgan('dev'));`

This should work.